# Eigenvalues of Matrix with 1s everywhere but diagonal

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm not sure if this type of matrix has a name, but I feel as if there's a trick to finding the eigenvalues that i'm missing:

$$ a \in R $$
$$
M = \begin{bmatrix}
       1 + a & 1 & 1           \\[0.3em]
       1 & 1 + a & 1 \\[0.3em]
       1 & 1 & 1+ a
     \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Note that $M=11^T+aI$

Answer (score 2):

Do you know the eigenvalues in the case $a = 0$?

Do you know the eigenvalues of $A + a \, I$, where $I$ is the identity in terms of the eigenvalues of $A$?

Comment: Am I right in saying for any matrix (n by n) of ones, the eigenvalues are n (once) and 0 (n-1 times). Then the eigenvalues of A + aI are lambda + am where lambda are the eigenvalues of A?

Answer (score 0):

The eigenvalues of $M$ are $a+3, \ a, \ a$.